# XPath evaluation issue

Tags: xpath

I am using xpath to get the siblings of a plugin by filtering on the artefactID of the maven pom.xml.

below is my xml .Using the Xpath expression **//plugin/artifactId[text()="test-maven"]** i am able to filter the elements , but i want to get the children siblings of the elements like "configuration" and the children inside it.  I tried modifying my Xpath to this way

**//plugin/artifactId[text()=\"test-maven\"]/../executions/execution/configuration**.It returns all the text inside the elements and i am unable to traverse or get the specific node name and value .

Can anyone help on how i can resolve this issue

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>net.xxx.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>xxx-test</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.20-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>apk</packaging>
    <name>xxx-test</name>

    <properties>
        <platform.version>2.3.3</platform.version>
        <android.sdk.version>3</android.sdk.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
            <artifactId>android</artifactId>
            <!--  <version>${platform.version}</version> -->
            <version>17</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2</groupId>
                <artifactId>android-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <androidManifestFile>${project.build.directory}/AndroidManifest.xml</androidManifestFile>
                    <assetsDirectory>${project.basedir}/assets</assetsDirectory>
                    <resourceDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</resourceDirectory>
                    <nativeLibrariesDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/native</nativeLibrariesDirectory>
                    <sdk>
                        <platform>17</platform>
                    </sdk>
                    <undeployBeforeDeploy>true</undeployBeforeDeploy>
                </configuration>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                 <groupId>org.xxxsource</groupId>
                  <artifactId>test-maven</artifactId>
                  <version>0.0.1</version>
                  <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Maven plugin</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>execute</goal>
                        </goals>
                       <configuration>
                                <fileToUpload>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.apk</fileToUpload> 
                                <!-- <secretKey>b3b47266-2d07-44d2-a4c4-23a64a2c9ff8</secretKey> 
                                 <uploadKey>e707d458-c9ae-4ce5-887f-8c70f97ad801-51334304-d180-4031-917f-a5c58768c7ba</uploadKey> -->

                                 <secretKey>b3b47266-211111111d07-44d2-a41111111c4-23a64a2c9ff8</secretKey> 
                                 <uploadKey>e707d458-c9ae-4ce111111111115-887f-8111111111111111c70f97ad801-51334304-d180-4031-917f-a5c58768c7ba</uploadKey>

                                <releaseNote>TEST</releaseNote> 
                                <grantUsers>
                                    <grantUser>c273ae88-2314-4d85-a7e5-2c2cd40638a8</grantUser>
                                    <grantUser>22a8d3df-7724-4941-8bd4-a735a807bc99</grantUser>
                                </grantUsers>
                       </configuration> 
                     </execution>
                </executions>          
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here is my code which I am using :-

```
                    Document doc = builder.parse(file);
        XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(path);
        Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            final Node node = (Node) nodes.item(i);
            System.out.println("Node  Name " + node.getNodeName());
            // System.out.println("Node  " + node.getTextContent());

            if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
                System.out.println("HAS Child");

                NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) node.getChildNodes();
                for (int j = 0; j < nodes1.getLength(); j++) {
                    final Node node1 = (Node) nodes1.item(j);
                    System.out.println("Node  Child " + node1.getNodeName()
                            + " value : =" + node1.getTextContent());
                }

            }
        }
```

Here is my ouyput:-

Node  Name configuration
HAS Child
Node  Child #text value : =

Node  Child fileToUpload value : =${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.apk
Node  Child #text value : =

Node  Child #comment value : = b3b47266-2d07-44d2-a4c4-23a64a2c9ff8 
                                 e707d458-c9ae-4ce5-887f-8c70f97ad801-51334304-d180-4031-917f-a5c58768c7ba 
Node  Child #text value : =

Node  Child secretKey value : =b3b47266-211111111d07-44d2-a41111111c4-23a64a2c9ff8
Node  Child #text value : =

Node  Child uploadKey value : =e707d458-c9ae-4ce111111111115-887f-8111111111111111c70f97ad801-51334304-d180-4031-917f-a5c58768c7ba
Node  Child #text value : =

Node  Child releaseNote value : =WLP_TEST from Maven
Node  Child #text value : =

Node  Child grantUsers value : =
                                    c273ae88-2314-4d85-a7e5-2c2cd40638a8
                                    22a8d3df-7724-4941-8bd4-a735a807bc99

Node  Child #text value : =

I am not sure why the #text node is getting printed and if we cane escape that.

Comment: That expression looks like it should select the right nodes (albeit in a bit of a convoluted way, `//plugin[artifactId='test-maven']/executions/execution/configuration` would be simpler), so the problem probably lies in the code that is _using_ the XPath expression rather than in the expression itself.

Comment: There are namespaces included in your XML, did you take care of them?

Comment: hello,  I have  added domFactory.setNamespaceAware(false); in my code. Is it not okay.  @Ian - i tried you appraoch it works on xpath but i don't get the elements object to iterate . I mean i get the whole content inside the configuration as a whole (textvalue()).  SO i am unable to figure out which value is for which element.

Comment: I tried using jDOM & w3c dom also still the value is printed as whole for configuration element.I want to get the elements under the configuration element and iterate it. I wonder is it related to some keyword  in parsing. i.e. configuration is a keyword and parsers hand it in some other way.

Comment: I'll ask again, how exactly are you using that XPath expression?  If you're using `javax.xml.xpath.XPath`, for example, then you must use the `evaluate` method that takes a `QName returnType`, and specify that you want a nodeset, as the two-argument `evaluate` always gives you the string value of the selected nodeset (the concatenation of all its text node descendants, in the case of an element) rather than the actual node(s).

Comment: XPathFactory factory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
 XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
 XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile(path);
 Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET); my code Ian.

Comment: i am getting the results but i see some values like for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
  final Node node = (Node) nodes.item(i);
  System.out.println("Node  Name " + node.getNodeName());
  if (node.hasChildNodes()) {
   System.out.println("HAS Child");
   NodeList nodes1 = (NodeList) node.getChildNodes();
   for (int j = 0; j < nodes1.getLength(); j++) {
    final Node node1 = (Node) nodes1.item(j);
    System.out.println("Node  Child " + node1.getNodeName()
      + " value : =" + node1.getTextContent());
   }

  }

Comment: HAS Child
Node  Child #text value : =
        
Node  Child fileToUpload value : =${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.apk
Node  Child #text value : = 
        
Node  Child #comment value : = <secretKey>b3b47266-2d07-44d2-a4c4-23a64a2c9ff8</secretKey> 
         <uploadKey>e707d458-c9ae-4ce5-887f-8c70f97ad801-51334304-d180-4031-917f-a5c58768c7ba</uploadKey> 
Node  Child #text value : =   What are these #text values , can i ignore them in my code , by default while parsing or do i have to handle it myself. I can see my node and it values

Comment: Code doesn't come across well in comments, any chance you could _edit_ the original question and put the code in there, suitably formatted?  Just indent code blocks by four space characters and make sure they have a blank line before and after the block, SO will do the rest.

Comment: Have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

getChildNodes() returns all nodes, including text ones (that much is obvious). Thus you have to filter out text nodes using `if (node1.nodeType == 1)` (there must be a constant for that `1` value though, consult your language/library manual to find out the name).